# Fetching facebook event feeds using graph api

Tags: facebook, events, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I was able to fetch facebook events through my code until couple of days back and it used to return me proper JSON data with all the requested fields.

Suddenly i am trying to do it today again and i get only `id` value and nothing else. Any idea what went wrong.

> http://graph.facebook.com/userid?limit=20&fields=events.fields(description,end_time,location,name,ticket_uri,venue)&access_token=access_token

is the request url format i am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `https://` when passing an `access token`.

Possibly, your access token don't let you fetch those details since you have not authorized your app to fetch `user_events`. You can check the access token [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/access_token).

So, you have to check whether the user have authorized your app for this action or not before making this query. You can also fetch the permissions that user has granted at any time using-

```
/me/permissions
```

Comment: Tried https as well, but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Updated the answer pls check